# Dúvida Array Solidity

Tags: blockchain

Eu estou tentando atribuir o valor de uma matriz para dois arrays, da seguinte forma:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract ArrayExamples {

    int[][] public matriz;


    // Os dados são recebidos da seguinte forma: [0,0]
    function receive_data(int[] data) public {
        matriz.push(data);
    }


    function teste() public returns (int[] v) {

        int[] x;
        int[] y;

        uint t = matriz.length;

        for(uint i = 0; i < t; i++) {

            x[i] = matriz[i][0];
            y[i] = matriz[i][1];

        }

        return x;
    }

  }
```

A matriz é dinâmica, mas no exemplo acima recebe como padrão um array com dois elementos. [0,0]

Quando faço a atribuição dos valores de x e y no for, apenas os valores de **y** são atribuídos corretamente. **x** fica responsável por pegar apenas o primeiro valor do array dinâmico da matriz e **y** pega o último valor.

Quando vou verificar o valor de **x**, consta que ele pegou o último valor do array dinâmico, sendo que ele devia pegar o primeiro valor do array.

Se eu entro com o seguinte array: [4,5] - tanto **x**, quanto **y** pegam 5, sendo que **x** devia pegar 4.